# Special characters in `template->renderObjectTemplate` method

Tags: plugin-development, plugins-formerly

Having a problem with the Formerly plugin where it is throwing an error if CSS is passed into the Submission body. Not sure if this is a Craft of a Formerly problem but looking into it further, the issue seems to occur when `!` or `;` are being passed into the `templates->renderObjectTemplate()` service - this results in an `Unexpected character` error being returned.

Any thoughts on how best to sanitise the input for this method so that form submission doesn't break?

Answer (score 1):

The has been solved (kinda) - turns out CSS was being passed into the `renderObjectTemplate` method for an email template. This meant that Twig was (understandably) trying to process the `{` and `}` characters as objects which was causing the service to throw a wobble.

Have stripped out the CSS for now and will see if there is another way we can pass these characters into the service without breaking it.

Many thanks @robin on the CraftCMS Slack for help identifying and debugging the problem.